# Attempting to use an array within an array to store and retrieve data. Having some isses

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loop iterating through various users (the counter is simply determining how many users to parse through). In every iteration a user's id and distance are stored in Array $friendObj. Then I want to add the $friendObj array to the $friendsArry. It does this, but each user iteration it replaces the data at the $friendArry[0] spot. Out of the five echo's at the end, only the first one displays anything and that data is the id of the very last user processed. Any suggestions to alter (or completely change my code) would be great (kind of new to php).

```
//...
//There is a loop above this cycling through different users.

        $friendObj = array('id' => $fId, 'distance' => $distanceFromYou);
        $friendsArry = array();
        array_push($friendsArry, $friendObj);
        echo "<br />";

        if($counter >= 5)
        {
            break;
        }
    } //end of loop
        echo "Test1: ". $friendsArry[0]['id']. "<br />";
        echo "Test2: ". $friendsArry[1]['id']. "<br />";
        echo "Test3: ". $friendsArry[2]['id']. "<br />";
        echo "Test4: ". $friendsArry[3]['id']. "<br />";
        echo "Test5: ". $friendsArry[4]['id']. "<br />";
```

Comment: Note (from the [`array_push`](http://php.net/array_push) documentation): "If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use `$array[] =` because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function." The empty-bracket syntax is mentioned in the [array type](http://php.net/array#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) manual page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting this line:

```
 $friendsArry = array($friendInc => friendObj);
```

I don't even understand what are you doing with that one.. o.O

Comment: oops. That was some left over code. I deleted it, doesn't really make any difference though. The problem still persist.

Comment: Then it's not the code you showed. It must be in the way you get $fId and $distanceFromYou because I tested that part and it's working properly.

Comment: Ohh duh. Sorry I was just initializing the array the in the loop every time. Thanks! I'll give you credit for the answer, you sort of inspired my revelation by reaffirming that my syntax was right.